# $\alpha,\epsilon$ elements of an abelian group. Show the following

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $\alpha, \beta$ are elements of an abelian group s.t $\alpha ^ 3 = \epsilon ^5=(\alpha\epsilon)^7=1$ how do I show that $\alpha =\epsilon=1$?

Using first part that subgroup $G=\langle\alpha,\epsilon\rangle  \subset S_7$ generated by cycles $\alpha =(1,2,3),\epsilon = (1,4,5,6,7)$ coinciding the commutator [G,G], how do I show that it is not solvable?

Comment: Could I say that since (3,5,7)=1 for the 1st part? I would appreciate a full solution

Comment: Hint:  $(\alpha\epsilon)^7=1\;\implies\;\alpha^7\epsilon^7=\alpha\epsilon^2=1\;\implies \;\alpha=\epsilon^{-2}$.

Comment: @lulu How do I show that G is not solvable? I was thinking of using the 1st part since we have a 7-cycle and then apply it on G/[G,G]

Comment: Sure.  $\frac {G}{[G,G]}$ is abelian, always, so the first part applies.  But since $G$ is generated by those two cycles, they must be trivial in the quotient, hence the quotient is trivial.

Comment: How concretely? I don't see it @lulu

Comment: You agree that that the quotient is abelian, yes?  But $\alpha^3=\epsilon^5=(\alpha\epsilon)^7=1$ in $G$ so these equalities certainly hold in the quotient (I am trusting you that the product is a $7$ cycle).

Comment: Indeed, it is a $7$ cycle.  So in the abelian quotient your conditions are met, so your two generators must be trivial.  Alas, that means the quotient itself is trivial so $G=[G,G]$.

Comment: I do understand this part but how do we get that not solvable since we know that it is solvable when $G^n=1$ @lulu

Comment: But if $G=[G,G]$ then $G^n=G$ for all $n$.   (perfect groups can't be solvable).

Answer (score 5):

As $G$ is abelian, you have $(\alpha\varepsilon)^7 = \alpha^7\varepsilon^7 = \alpha\varepsilon^2 = 1$

So, $(\alpha\varepsilon^2)^3 = \alpha^3 \varepsilon^6 = \varepsilon^6 = 1$.

As $\varepsilon^5 = 1$, you can deduce $\varepsilon = 1$, and then $\alpha = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the group is abelian, $(\alpha\epsilon)^7=1$ implies $\alpha^7=\epsilon^{-7}$. Then $\alpha^7 \in \langle \alpha \rangle \cap \langle \epsilon \rangle=1$, because $\gcd(3,5)=1$.

So, $\alpha=\alpha^7=1$ and then $\epsilon^7=(\alpha\epsilon)^7=1$. Finally, $\epsilon=\epsilon^{15-14}=\epsilon^{15}\epsilon^{-14}=(\epsilon^{5})^3(\epsilon^{7})^{-2}=1$.